# Memory overwrites in C++ code showing up in consistent locations

Tags: c++, memory

I have a very un-scientific observation about memory overwrites and was curious if anyone else has noticed something similar, knows why, and/or can tell me why I wasn't really seeing what I thought I was seeing.

What I noticed was that for some C++ programs, when I have a memory overwrite bug in that program, it would usually (if not always) show up in a specific section of code which was often unrelated to the section of code with the bug. This is not a blanket observation. Not all C++ programs behave this way. But when I have one, it is pretty consistent. (No comment on why my code has enough memory overwrites that I have the opportunity to notice consistent-anything :) )

I'm not asking why a memory overwrite in function1 can show up in function2; that is understood. My observation is that over the life of a given program, we have discovered memory overwrites in function1, function2, function3, function4, and function5. But in each case, we discovered the problem because the code would crash in function6. Always in function6 and only in function6. None of those functions are related and do not touch anything that function6 uses.

Over my lifetime, I've encountered two C programs and one C++ program that behaved this way. These were years apart in unrelated systems and hardware. I just found it weird and wondered if anyone else has seen this. Plus, I suspect that I may be seeing the same pattern in a C++/JNI/Java program that I'm working on now, but it is young enough that I've not had enough hits to be sure of a pattern.

Comment: This is asking for opinions and is a bit fuzzy so it will probably be closed.  My opinion:  the corruption probably was consistent because it was involving stack variables, and stack frame allocations stay the same until you change the code.   Consider `char foo[4], bar[4];`  -- a buffer overrun in `foo` is going to keep corrupting `bar` every time you run the program.

Comment: ..and/.or possibly `int baz;` if the compiler ordered the stack frame that way.  The point is that stack frame variable order is not randomized.  The compiler puts them in the same order (whatever that happens to be) until the code changes.  I could see the same thing happening with some memory allocations on the heap if they always happen in the same order at program startup for some global objects.  Also, corruption within a struct or class object is going to behave like the stack frame since the object is allocated as one chunk of heap

Comment: I don't really see any specific question here. Stories of interesting bugs may be fun, but is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: This falls under a very broad conclusion of "sometimes programs do things consistently". But other times they're influenced by various factors that make things practically inconsistent. There's not much more to say in general. The consistency-or-not of how a problem behaves is very dependent on the details.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is not a good question and will have no heartburn if it disappears entirely, even with some negative rep. I've held this belief for a long time, but a wild hair made me post about it. :) Thanks to everyone who took the time to read and respond. Your time was not totally wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the real question here is about what escalates "silent" memory corruption into an actual/formal crash (as opposed to "just" more subtle problems such as unexpected data values, that the user might or might not notice or recognize).  I don't think that question can be answered generally, as it depends a lot on the specifics of the compiler, the code, the memory layout of the in-memory data structures, etc.

It can be said that in most modern (non-embedded) systems there is an MMU that handles translating virtual (i.e. per-process) memory addresses into physical memory addresses, and that many user-space crashes are the result of the MMU generating an unrecoverable page fault when the user program tries to dereference a virtual address that has no defined physical equivalent.  So perhaps in this case `function6()` was trying to dereference a pointer whose value had been corrupted in such a way that the MMU couldn't translate it to a physical address.  Note that the compiler often places its own pointers on the stack (to remember where the program's control flow should return to when a function returns), so a bad pointer dereference can happen even in code that doesn't explicitly dereference any pointers.

Another common cause for a crash would be a deliberately induced crash invoked by code that notices that the data it is working with is "in a state that should never happen" and calls `abort()` or similar.  This can happen in user code that has `assert()` calls in it, or in system-provided code such as the code that manages the process's heap.  So it could be that `function6()` tried to allocate or free heap memory, and in so doing gave the heap manager the chance to detect an "impossible state" in one of its data structures and crash out.  Keep in mind that the process's heap is really just one big data structure that is shared by all parts of the program that use the heap, so it's not terribly surprising that heap corruption caused by one part of the program might result in a crash later on by another (mostly unrelated) part of the program that also uses the heap.

Comment: I too have seen buffer overflows trigger sanity checks in heap-management library functions.